# How to make a jQuery draggable actually snap to an equally sized droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have my draggable and droppable setup correctly using jquery-ui.  They are both the same size, so the draggable should fit nicely on to the droppable.  Is there any way to make the draggable snap in to the middle of the droppable so as to completely cover it?  It seems if I use the snap: parameter it just snaps to the edges, and not necessarily to the middle of the droppable.

Comment: Define `middle`. Did you check `spanMode` option?

Comment: By middle I mean if I have 2 objects that exactly the same size, I want the draggable one to snap to completely obscure the droppable one.  snapMode: 'inner' helps a little, but it can still snap to not being centered.

Comment: Come back with a sample code.

Comment: This guy actually solved the problem:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-draggable-new-snapmode-corner-21-2-2011
snap: 'corner'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Would this not do the job, give or take a pixel:

```
    drop: function(event, ui) { 
    $(ui.draggable).offset($(this).offset());
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Or since you're already using jQuery UI, there's the [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) method

```
drop: function(event, ui) { 
  ui.draggable.position({of: $(this)});
}
```